# Evaluating the indefinite integral $\int\sqrt{\cos2x}\sin^32x\,dx$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I have tried to integrate the following indefinite integral but I'm not sure if I get the right answer. Please tell me if I'm wrong and if so, please indicate what went wrong.

$$
\int\sqrt{\cos2x}\sin^32x\,dx
$$
$$
\int\sqrt{\cos2x}(\sin^22x)(\sin2x)\,dx
$$
$$
\int\sqrt{\cos2x}(1-\cos^22x)(\sin2x)\,dx
$$
$$
\frac {-1}2 \int\sqrt{u}(1-u^2)\,du
$$
$$
\frac {-1}2 \int(u^{\frac 12}-u^{\frac 52})\,du
$$
$$
\frac {-1}2 (\frac {2u^{\frac 32}}3-\frac {2u^{\frac 72}}7)\,+C
$$
$$
\frac {u^{\frac 72}}7-\frac {u^{\frac 32}}3\,+C
$$
$$
\frac {\sqrt{\cos^72x}}7-\frac {\sqrt{\cos^32x}}3\,+C
$$

Comment: The answer is correct. Next time, it is a better idea to first check whether the result of the integral is correct using e.g. Wolfram|Alpha, Maple, or Mathematica.

Comment: The process is certainly right. The details also look right.

Comment: I tried with Wolfram|Alpha before writing here, that's what made me wonder whether the result was correct. (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28%28cos2x%29%5E%281%2F2%29sin%C2%B3%282x%29%29+dx)

Comment: Why not try some trig identities to show your answer is the same as WA's?

Comment: You can check the correctness by differentiating the result. Differentiating your result gives the original function, so it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fact that $\cos^3 2x = \frac{\cos 6x+3 \cos 2x}{4}$ you get the answer given by Wolfram Alpha.